# Entity Framework: Check if value is nothing without reading all the data?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am looking for a way to test a db field via an EF query simply to see if it is null or not, but without reading the entirety of the data. If it's not null, it's going to be huge and there are many rows, so doing this the standard way (as in the snippet below) is a very heavy operation on the db and takes ages. What I would like is to just let the user know which rows have some data in that field, and then they can choose to view it, which will then perform a single operation on that row to return just that data.

I feel like this should be possible, testing to see if something has a value or not doesn't require reading all of the data, so is there a way to achieve the desired result?

```
Class MyClassModel 
   Property HasData As Boolean?

   Function Query (DB as DBContext)  As IEnumerable(Of MyClassLineModel)
    Dim data As IQueryable(Of MyClass) = DB.MyClasses

        If HasData.HasValue Then data = From t In data Where t.Data IsNot Nothing = HasData

                    Dim ret = (From t In data Select New MyClassLineModel With {    
                                    .HasData = t.Data IsNot Nothing}).ToArray

        Return ret
  End Function 
End Class

Class MyClassLineModel 
    Property HasData As Boolean?
End Class
```

p.s. This is an MVC project, hence the "model" etc. But this question is still applicable in general.

---

EDIT

NVM, turns out that EF does this for me. The above code converts to a db query

```
CASE WHEN Data IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

which doesn't read the whole field. Response time is fine. Mods can delete the Q, or keep it for anyone else who wants to know. Thanks for all the answers guys.

Comment: 1. Create an index on the column you are searching on; 2. Use a filter to only retrieve non empty rows, and probably add a `Take` to return a reasonable amount (that can be displayed to the user). Your question actually doesn't make sense from a database perspective. You can't test "a field". You can test a field in combination with some rows (a tuple) or you can test every row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .Any() - if you use this on a IQueryable backed by SQL it will do something like a WHERE EXISTS in SQL which won't read all the data...

i.e.

```
var dataExists = _dataContext.Entity.Any(e => e.Field != NULL);
```